# How to pass variable through template Data in meteor js?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, blaze

I want to pass data through template but i am getting undefined i have two variables inside the customer template and when user click i want to pass these two var to the next template customerchathistory like

```
Template.customer.events({
  async 'click .list-chat'(event,template) {
    const Rid = event.currentTarget.id;
    const Rtoken = event.currentTarget.token;
 }
})
```

Here i am passing those var like this in customer.html

```
{{>cutomerChatHistory clickRid= Rid clickRtoken = Rtoken }}
```

Now when i am fetching these two var inside the customerChatHistory.js i am getting undefined

```
Template.customerChatHistory.onCreated(function() {
 const currentData = Template.currentData();
console.log(currentData.clickRid , currentData.clickRtoken) //giving undefined here
})
```

Comment: Please add the html files for both Templates, it's otherwise unclear where you pass which data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `Rid` and `Rtoken` variables in helpers so that they become available in Blaze html template :

```
Template.customer.events({
  async 'click .list-chat'(event,template) {
    template.Rid.set(event.currentTarget.id);
    template.Rtoken.set(event.currentTarget.token);
 }
})

Template.customer.helpers({
  Rid: function(){
     return Template.instance().Rid.get();
  }
  Rtoken: function(){
     return Template.instance().Rtoken.get();
  }
})

Template.customer.onCreated({
  this.Rid = new ReactiveVar(null)
  this.Rtoken = new ReactiveVar(null)
})
```